# Difference between Let and Use function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, lambda, functional-programming

I went through the code samples of "let" and "use" methods of Kotlin. But I couldn't figure out any difference between the two code samples and specific differences between their use cases. The code samples are written below.

```
//use method
    fun main(args: Array) {
    val file = File("input"+File.separator+"contents.txt")
    file.bufferedReader().use{
        println(it.readText())
    }
}

//let method.
var name : String? = "Kotlin let null check"
name?.let { println(it) }
```

Can someone explain what is the difference between these two methods and their use cases? Thank You.

Comment: See the documentation of [`use`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html); it has an entirely different purpose from [`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html).

Comment: `use` is used for similar purpose but closes the AutoCloseable object once the given block completes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're doing very different things.

[`use()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html) is used to ensure that a resource gets closed even in the event of an error.  It can only be called on objects implementing the [`Closeable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) interface, and is a sort of equivalent to the Java [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) construct, but `use()` is a simple library function and doesn't need any new language syntax.

In your example, it's ensuring that the `BufferedReader` gets `close()`d whether the `readText()` call completes normally or throws an `IOException` or whatever.  (It's quite important to close external resources cleanly under all circumstances; Kotlin makes this as easy as possible.)

[`let()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) is a [scope function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#let) (like [`apply()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html), [`also()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/also.html), [`run()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html), and [`with()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html)); it can be called on any object (or even `null`), and its purpose is to change the context within a block of code.  In this case, within the block `it` refers to the value on which the `let` was called, and the block's return value becomes the result of the `let`.  It can be used to turn a sequence of related assignments into a chain of calls — especially when intermediate values might be null, where the `?.` safe-call operator can avoid lots of `if`s.

In your example, it's calling `println()` only if `name` is not null.  The alternative would be:

```
if (name != null)
    println(name)
```

In this case that extra line isn't *much* longer, and neither is having to repeat `name`; but you can see that in a more complex example, the saving could be significant.